# Solace - Failed to create InitialContext when the solace jar was upgraded to v10.1

Tags: java, spring

We have upgraded the solace version from 7.1 to 10.1 for an existing spring based application. After upgrading it, we started the application and observed the below error. Is new solace jar causing this error?

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solaceConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [SolRes.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hashtable [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]

Comment: You might have to share your SolRes.xml and the full exception stack trace in your logs.

Comment: sure, i have posted it below as requested.

Comment: Hi Szocske, Could you please assist based on the details I had shared. Thanks